# Programmatically inserting tables into OneNote

Tags: c#, onenote-api

Is there any way to programmatically insert a table into a one note document? I notice that the OneNote API doesn't define something of that matter.

If anyone knows a way on how to do this and could give me some resources to try and look at that would be variable. The reason I want to know if this is possible is because eventually I want to take contents of a word file which may contain a table and transfer that to a OneNote File.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are looking to use the OneNote REST API, you can use PATCH ~/pages/id/content to "append" an HTML table to a OneNote page. Here's an example:

https://dev.onenote.com/docs#/reference/patch-pages/v10menotespagesidcontent/patch

```
PATCH https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/pages/{ID}/content
Content-Type: application/json

[{
  'target': 'body',
  'action': 'append',
  'content': '<table>...</table>'
}]
```